# How do i hide a radio button that i no longer need?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a RadioButtonList which is generated from SQL database with only two values, radio1 "Economy (3 days)" and radio2 "Next day (Overnight)". now i only want to keep radio1 and hide rid of radio2. i'm struggling since these radio buttons are not added individually, they are populated when data is added to this database.

e.g i have two values on the database that populate 2 radio buttons, if i added more data on the table, the radio buttons would increase as well.

Now i only want to keep radio1 and get rid of radio2. the only way i thought of doing this worked but, i went and deleted the second value, which looked nice, but caused the website to misbehave, so i went and added the value back on the database. now im wondering if theres anything i can do on the code to hide the second radio button.

HTML Markup

```
<input type="radio" name="rd_deliveryoption" value="<%# Eval("iDeliveryID")%>" <%# Eval("bIsDelivery").ToString() == "True" ? Convert.ToInt16(Eval("iItemID")) == Convert.ToInt16(Eval("iDeliveryID")) ? "checked" : "" : ""  %> <%# Eval("bIsDelivery").ToString() == "False" ? "style=display:none;'" : "" %>/>
```

I want the page to have 1 radio button and hide the second 1.

Comment: If the question is how to hide an HTML element using JS, then why are we seeing reams of C#? If you want to change the two radios to one checkbox for example, then post the rendered HTML

Comment: u have only listed one radio button which one you want to hide show the HTML part not server

Comment: @marcelo like i mentioned, the radios are populated when more data is added. that's how it was initially done by the previous developer, that's why i'm finding it hard to now fix it to what i want. Hence i'm here.

Comment: so there will be an 'N' number of radio buttons with the same data or different?

Comment: @marcelo radio1 is for economy, radio2 is for overnight delivery, if i was to add another delivery method, another radio would be populated, etc, but i only want to hide the overnight delivery since i don't need it.

Comment: what is the id or name of that radio button that populates overnight delivery?

Comment: @marcelo the html markup you see it is how it is done. both id and name are there

Comment: ok can u inspect the radio button in the browser when its value is overnight delivery and find what ```Eval=iDeliveryID``` its having

Comment: @marcelo the value is 4

Comment: check the answer i have provided

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```css
input[type=radio]:not(:first-of-type) { display:none }
```

```html
<input type="radio"><input type="radio"><input type="radio"><input type="radio"><input type="radio">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `test` as the id check using this

```html
<input type="radio" id=test name="rd_deliveryoption" value="<%# Eval("iDeliveryID")%>" <%# Eval("bIsDelivery").ToString() == "True" ? Convert.ToInt16(Eval("iItemID")) == Convert.ToInt16(Eval("iDeliveryID")) ? "checked" : "" : ""  %> <%# Eval("bIsDelivery").ToString() == "False" ? "style=display:none;'" : "" %>/>
```

```js
  $(window).ready(function () {
            alert('hai')
            radiohide();
        });
        function radiohide() {
            alert('wassup')
            if (document.getElementById('test').value==4) {


                document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';

            }
            else {
//do whatever you want

            }

        }
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and DOM access in a question not flagged as jQuery?

Comment: Also `=` is assign and `==` or `===` is comparison `window.addEventListener("load",radiohide);

function radiohide() {
  if (document.getElementById('test').value == 4) {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    /*do whatever you want */
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys finally got it right, i added this to my css

```
tr.nextday {
    display:none !important;
}
```

then this to my mark up

```
 <tr class="<%# Eval("sDesc").ToString().Replace(" ","")%>">
```

Answer (score -3):

Could You not just use some CSS & JS - using display:none;?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: What did you try so far? ill see if i can help any further